# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I know there are many questions like this, but i didn't find any solution in it.

Things i tried:-

- checked firewall
- restarted my PC and Apache server
- restarted MYSQL
- checked my code
- Tried everything i know and found on internet

here's my code:-

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost:3360';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db     = 'test_db13';


$conn  = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,'',$db);

if(! $conn){
  die('Could not connect connect: ') ;
}

echo 'Successfully Connected';


$sql = 'Connected Successfully';
  $retvalue = mysqli_query($sql);

  if(! $retvalue){
    die('Cannot connect to SQL: ');
  }

echo 'DataBase test_db13 has successfully created';

mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

I did set the password, but it still is showing me the error.

Here's the firewall picture:-
[image]

lastly XAMMP is running here's the proof

[image]

Comment: Look at the port given in your control panel, and the one you use to connect with. `3360` != `3306`

Comment: in your PHP, the port is 3360, whereas xampp is suggesting it's 3306

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you look at your XAMPP Control Panel, it's clearly stated that the port to the MySQL server is `3306` - you provided `3360`. The `3306` is default, and thus doesn't need to be specified. Even so, the 5th parameter of `mysqli_connect()` is the port, which is where it should be specified.

You could just remove the port specification altogether, as you're using the default port, making it

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db     = 'test_db13';
```

References

- [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)
- [Standard connection of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-standard.html)

Comment: this looks suspiciously similar to my answer

Comment: I already pointed it out in the comments though, before any answers was posted ;-) And the only reason they look similar, is because it's the easiest fix for his issue! Great minds think alike, eh?

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly my problem.  one day i'll understand why 3306 is such a sensitive port number to use.

Answer (score 7):

You have entered wrong port number 3360 instead of 3306.
You dont need to write database port number if you are using daefault (3306 in case of MySQL)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a non default MySQL port number then do the following:

1. Stop your xampp/wamp/etc session
2. Set port number used by MySQL in *config.inc.php* under the phpMyAdmin folder.
3. For example if your MySQL port number is `33747` then paste the following

   ```php
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 33747;
   ```

   under the

   ```php
   /* Authentication type and info */
   ```

   section.
4. Restart Apache and MySQL servers.

Comment: After 6 hours of agony, this is the only solution that worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

For those who came here looking for the answer and didnt type 3306 wrong...If like myself, you have wasted hours with no luck searching for this answer, then possibly this may help.

If you are seeing this:
(HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Then my understanding is that it cant connect for one of the following below. Now which..

1) is your wamp, mamp, etc icon GREEN? Either way, right-click the icon --> click tools --> test both the port used for Apache (typically 80) and for Mariadb (3307?). Should say 'It is correct' for both.

2) Error comes from a .php file. So, check your dbconnect.php.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_pw";
$dbname = "your_dbname";
$port = "3307";
?>
```

Is your setup correct? Does your user exist? Do they have rights? Does port match the tested port in 1)? Doesn't have to be 3307 and user can be root. You can also left click the green icon --> click MariaDB and view used port as shown in the image below. All good? Positive? ok!

[image]

3) Error comes when you login to phpmyadmin. So, check your my.ini.

[image]

Open my.ini by left clicking the green icon --> click MariaDB -->

```
; The following options will be passed to all MariaDB clients
[client]
;password = your_password
port = 3307
socket = /tmp/mariadb.sock

; Here follows entries for some specific programs

; The MariaDB server
[wampmariadb64]
;skip-grant-tables
port = 3307
socket = /tmp/mariadb.sock
```

Make sure the ports match the port MariaDB is being testing on. Then finally..

```
[mysqld]
port = 3307
```

At the bottom of my.ini, make sure this port matches as well.

4) 1-3 done? restart your WAMP and cross your fingers!

Answer (score 4):

It is just a matter of changing the port user by mysql:3308 to 3306

Just right click on wamp-> select tools

under Port Used By mysql:3308 clcik on "use a port other than 3308

In the text port text box appear : type 3306 and save. Wait until the wampserver restarts and get green.

Now run your PHP code, It will work. That's it - Good Luck

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution. I wasted hours just trying to figure what this issue was. I tried deleting all those files suggested above and it didn't work for me, I tried adding new inbound rules to firewall for myslqd.exe and it didn't work. The thing that is causing this error is MySQL port is misconfigured and the fix was really simple. if you are using **Wamp or Xampp** go to  **Main Folder/Bin/mysql/mysql/** and find a file named **my.ini**

Open **my.ini** file press **CTRL + F** and inside it search for **PORT** and **change whatever value of port to - 3306** and **save file**;

After that go to Wamp icon at the bottom of the taskbar (system tray) and **left click** choose mysql option and click **"test port 3306 used"** and see if it gives you any error. you can also click **use other port other than** whatever is shown there  and port 3306.

Goodluck. if it works comment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjgmI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP code you have set the incorrect port, this is what the code should be

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db     = 'test_db13';
```

The port in your code is set to `3360` when it should be `3306`, however as this is the default port, you don't need to specify.

Answer (score 0):

In most of cases it is data log problem. Follow the steps.

i) Go to data folder of mysql. 
   For xampp go to C:\xampp\mysql\data.

ii) Look for log file name like ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.

iii) Create backup and delete those files.

iv) Restart apache and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in other words it is being said that the port you wish to use for this project is already in use by another project .

It is something frequent while working with several projects .

Changing the port you wish to work on is a solution.

If you are using xampp

1)Open xampp

2)Click on config found at mysql section

3)You will see a file named my.ini which will pop up

4)Open the file

5)Use Ctrl+H to open the find and replace

6)Replace the port number with another port which coincide with the new port you will use in your project

7) Restart xampp and here you go.