# SQL Debug Message: 2002) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I'm getting the almost infamous

```
(HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Connection failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

error messages in trying to get PHP to talk to MySQL.

Configure
PHP is 7.3.7 (NTS MSCV15 (Visual c++ 2017) x64)
MySQL is 8.0.17 on a localhost (127.0.0.1)
IIS Windows 10 (10.0.18362.1)

All of this is running locally on laptop at 127.0.0.1 (though the corporate network is a 10.0.?.?)

IT support has spent the best part of 2 hours looking at all network and firewall issues (to the point disabled all firewall and enabled basically all the ports) and nothing seems to get through

MySQL is running, the username and passwords are perfectly fine, the hosts file has a correct DNS entry and the code is correct.

```
<?php
$servername = "rackforms";
$username = "rackforms";
$password = "????????";
$port = "3312";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $port);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

MySQL port has been deliberately moved to 3312. Use other MySQL instances on 3306. Really it shouldn't make difference.

I've looked at XAMPP and WAMP and other *AMP entries without much luck and spent way too much time on SO.

Any suggestions on what else to do?

Thanks

RESOLVED!!
Need to change the mysql.default_port in php.ini to the same port I am using for MySQL database. Not sure if there is a way to override this port using a connection string as (at least on Windows) seems to be ignored based on comments in php.ini

Comment: try not giving the port name. #comment out the $port variable and try running the code.

Comment: actually the fourth parameter is there to give the database name. not the port no.

Comment: you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810171/mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-m

Comment: As far as I can go . The error is in Port no. Because on trying other Port No. I get the same error.. try checking of your MySQL port is the same or not being used by the other server/application

Comment: as @AbnitChauhan said the database connection syntax is `<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "database";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_conncect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo “Connected successfully”;

mysqli_close($conn);

?>`