# phpmyadmin shows access denied

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is the error message I am getting. Can someone please help me solve it.

````
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.```
````

Comment: check if your mysql server is running or you have correctly defined server address

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810171/mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-m/39810359