# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to connect a cpanel phpmyadmin database to a products page to my website for designing a shopping cart, and I keep getting that error above even though I'm connect. Any ideas why I'm getting this error

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME');


$query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by ID ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            print_r($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cpanel phpmyadmin database` does not exist. You are using a mysql database. cpanel is a UI you are using to manager your server and phpmyadmin is a ui you are using to interact with DB.

Comment: This means the MySQL server isn't running on your machine.

Comment: Take a look at the phpMyAdmin configuration.  What database server is it connecting to?  If Barmar is correct, which is possible, then it's because there is no mysql process running on your server.  It could also be because mysql is not configured to run on it's well known port (3306).  MySQL might also be running on an entirely different server.  It depends on your hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

this error shows when the port number that you set for mysql connection is wrong.check the port number and it should work.
also see this:
[mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810171/mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-m)